# no puedo abrir php con visual studio code en navegador

Tags: php, visual-studio

no puedo abrir un archivo php en navegador desde visual studio code  con live serve
pero cuando lo abro con xampp si se puede ver su contenido.
alguien que me diga que puedo hacer para poder abrilo desde visual studio code?

Comment: Php es un lenguaje de backend, eso quiere decir que necesita un servidor para que 'sea entendido' si lo abre con xamp, lo estaras abriendo con un servidor y este sabra 'entender' ese lenguaje, en cambio al abrirlo con el IDE te lo abre como una pagina de frontend. El live server que mencionas seguramente se refiere a crear un entorno en el que detecte los cambios y se autorefresque, pero para cosas como : cambios de js, html, css, y cosas de front.

Comment: muchas gracias por  constestar. entoces que servidor podria usar? soy nueva y no se mucho sobre el tema

Comment: @ckef para PHP en Windows te alcanza con xampp o wampp para que dicho código sea interpretado

Comment: @ckef te aconsejo que instales xamp, y que guardes tus ficheros.php en el directorio `/htdocs` de xamp, arranca el servidor xampp y te vas a la ruta por defecto : `localhost` 'barra' el nombre del fichero que quieres ver

Comment: te invitamos a darte una vuelta por el chat : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: @ckef en el chat creo que encontraras mas apoyo.. saludos